# Software to add multiple references to different pages in the same document and export it as PDF

Tags: pdf, images, hyperlink, reference-management

I have an image that looks like this:
[image]

I'm looking for a way to add a reference to each of the marked points (either red dots or the letters, or generally speaking any place on the image) and have it point to a different page within same document. I tried making it work in word, but with no success. In other words what I want to do is select an area on an image(or in the document in general) that will be a reference(hyperlink?) to another page within the same document. Afterwards it is expected to be created as PDF.

Comment: Is this something you're looking to develop yourself or are you looking for an end-user product ready to go out of the box?  Any particular budget you're working with?

Comment: I'm mainly wondering if anything like that is possible in existing software, especially the likes of MS Word, Adobe Acrobat etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure that it will transfer well to a pdf but you can get this sort of functionality in just about any browser by using the html image map functionality. You define the regions of the image that you need to act as links and the URL - which can be on the same page, site or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the image in an `<img...>` element on a standard HTML web page, create a clickable HTML imagemap (there are interactive editors for that).

Then turn your HTML page into a [PDF, using Chrome in headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#create_a_pdf). This would be a command-line call to Google Chrome.

I haven't done this with imagemaps, yet. Only with standard web pages. But Chrome works very well even with complex CSS stylesheets.